# Change the marker of stripplot seaborn to be a string, not a marker

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| NAME | POSITION | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 0.1 |
| B | 34 | 0.8 |

If I create a plot with stripplot, is there a way to have the dots actually be the corresponding values in NAME?

For example, the plot on the tutorial ([https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html)) shows this plot. Could those dots be replaced with the strings in another column, for example in "NAME"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the following (just tested it on my stripplot I am working on)

```
sns.stripplot(data=yourdata, x=‘column_from_your_data’, size=2’)
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, markers can be set to any string by Dollars($).

`sns.lineplot(data,marker="$string$")`

You should probably also play with markersize to make it prettier.

`sns.lineplot(data,marker="$string$", markersize=10)`

Comment: The post author asked about stripplot not lineplot, this doesn’t work for stripplot, I just tested it